# Json not getting to server

Tags: php, jquery, json, slim

Have the following js:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(DispAplazados);
console.log(json);

$.ajax({
    url: API_URL + '/distanciamiento/alerta'
,   type: 'POST'
,   contentType: 'application/json'
,   data: {data:json} //stringify is important
,   headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(API_USERNAME + ':' + API_PASSWORD)
    }
,   success: function(res)
            {
                if (res.status == 'OK') 
                {
                    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                        title: 'Alerta',
                        text: 'Se mando una alerta a la BD...' + DispAplazados[0].Hashid,
                        foreground: true
                    });
                    console.log(res);
                }
                else
                {
                   console.log(res);
                }    
            }
});
```

In slim (php) Ive done:

```
print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE);
```

But the array is empty.
The log of the json stringified object is the following:

```
[{"name":"moto g(7) play","id":"63:D3:FC:7E:C9:32","advertising":{},"rssi":-60,"distancia_aproximada":1.1352362990362899,"Hashid":"6a5caba3-f30b-cbbf-3726-f11851500422","dispositivo_central":"d8504723c61da70","acumulador_segundos":60}]
```

Am I doing something wrong in the ajax call?

Comment: Haved you checked the contents of php://input? var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));

Comment: Ive used 
$chd = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$childs = implode("",$chd);
and then returned it on ajax call and gives me null

Comment: Check what `file_get_contents('php://input')` actually returned first of all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the data in the Ajax call to:

```
,    data: json
```